# android picks wrong image from drawable folder

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources, mdpi

My sample app has these res folders:

```
drawable-hdpi

drawable-ldpi

drawable-mdpi

drawable-xhdpi

drawable-xxhdpi
```

In each folder, I have a display.png which shows which folder is from.
I tested my app on my **mi max** phone which has a density of 440dpi and a resolution of 1920px-by-1080px, but Android always picks the image from the `drawable-mdpi` folder.

My phone density should be `xhdpi`, right?
Why is Android picking the image from the `mdpi` bucket, then?

Comment: n my experience, if you place an image in just some of the drawable folders, but not all, the OS will choose the "best" image for the device that you are using, even if it is not exactly the perfect fit.

Comment: Have you added `<supports-screens>` in `manifest` file.

Comment: refer to below link I dont need to.   "However, if your application supports all screen sizes supported by Android (as small as 426dp x 320dp), then you don't need to declare this attribute, because the smallest width your application requires is the smallest possible on any device."   https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: You must add  images in different drawable folder with **same name** else, it wont care about phone density

Comment: I do that this is my source code  https://www.dropbox.com/s/g6j1o7vk5qejvzw/ScreenInfo.rar?dl=0

Comment: I am having the same kind of issue difference being Android picking the image from ldp.

Answer (score 1):

Create an sample application with below code to check whether it's which density device.

```
density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

code will return below values based on your devices density .

```
return 0.75 if it's LDPI
return 1.0 if it's MDPI
return 1.5 if it's HDPI
return 2.0 if it's XHDPI
return 3.0 if it's XXHDPI
return 4.0 if it's XXXHDPI
```

I have query, how you came to know the device taking image from mdpi folder ?

Comment: I run that it return 2.75

Comment: how you came to know the device taking image from mdpi folder?
did you placed different image with same name ??

Comment: Some devices are causing the similar issues, Nexus5X returns 2.5.

Comment: this is my source code  https://www.dropbox.com/s/g6j1o7vk5qejvzw/ScreenInfo.rar?dl=0

Comment: may you can refer this link for density related info  [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)